# Unable to generate Rigs from Meta-Rigs

Tags: rigging, rigify

I am new to Blender. I imported a third party 3D model and I added in a human meta-rig and formed it to fit the human model. But when I click "generate" button under rigify, the blender page gets shut down.

Here is the [Dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u1goj0bu6pdl3yp/juliet.blend?dl=0) for my .blend file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I checked your file, but couldn't recreate your problem. Rig certainly could use some more care, especially on hands area, but Rigify works and your file is not corrupted, so the cause of your issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: Could try opening a new file and appending rig / mesh etc into that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I worked on both the advice and it worked. I opened it in new file and worked on finer detail of fingers. It worked like a charm. Thanks again.